# Kendo UI: Destroy and create command in kendo-grid goes throw multiple times to actions using ASP.NET MVC Web API controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui

I have problem with my application which use Kendo UI. After I call destroy command in kendo-grid I will see in browser debugger that program goes through multiple actions in POcontroller(`/api/po/postpo` and `/api/po/deletepo`). Sometimes action `/api/po/deletepo`calls more than two or more times after `/api/po/postpo` action. Program behavior is also very strange when I call create action and in debugger I can see multiple calls of `/api/po/postpo`.

Here is Kendo UI configuration and Web API controller:

**POControllers.cs**

```
using Dashy.DB.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Dashy.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Inspections;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Dashy.Controllers
{
    public class POController : ApiController
    {
        public IQueryable<PO> GetPOs()
        {
            using(PODAL podal = new PODAL())
            {
                podal.BeginTransaction();
                return podal.GetAll().AsQueryable();
            }
        }
        public HttpResponseMessage PostPO([Bind(Exclude = "id,po_lines")]PO po)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (PODAL podal = new PODAL())
                {
                    podal.BeginTransaction();
                    podal.SavePO(po);
                }
                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, po);
                response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = po.id }));
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
            }

        }
        public IHttpActionResult PutPO(PO po)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }


            try
            {
                using (PODAL podal = new PODAL())
                {
                    podal.UpdatePO(po);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage DeletePO(PO po)
        {

            if (po == null)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            using (PODAL podal = new PODAL())
            {
                try
                {
                    podal.BeginTransaction();
                    podal.DeletePO(po);
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, po);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.PartialContent, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**homeController.js**

```
app.controller('homeController', function ($scope, $http, poDataSource, poLinesDataSource) {

    $scope.dataSource = poDataSource;

    $scope.gridColumns = [
            { field: "id", title: "ID" },
            { field: "po_number", title: "PO nr" },
            { field: "valid_start", title: "Start date" },
            { field: "valid_end", title: "End date" },
            { field: "note", title: "Note" },
            { template: "<input type='text' ng-value='calculateTotal(dataItem)' />", title: "Total"},
            {
                command: [{ template: "<button class='k-button' ng-click='showDetails(dataItem)'>Show details</button>", }],
                title: "Show details",
            },

            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: " " }
    ];
})
```

**poDataSource.js**

```
'use strict';

app.factory('poDataSource',
    function () {
        return new kendo.data.DataSource({

            transport: {
                    type: "odata",
                    read: {
                        url: '/api/po/getpos',
                        type: 'GET',
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: '/api/po/putpo',
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "PUT",
                        contentType: "application/json"
                    },
                    destroy: {
                        url: 'api/po/deletepo',
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "DELETE",
                        contentType: "application/json"
                    },
                    create: {
                        url: "/api/po/postpo",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                            if (operation !== "read") {
                                return JSON.stringify(options);

                        }
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 5,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "id",
                        fields: {
                            id: { editable: false, nullable: false, type:"number" },
                            po_number: { type: "string" },
                            note: { type: "string" },
                            valid_start: { type: "date" },
                            valid_end: { type: "date" },
                            po_lines : { editable: false, nullable: true}
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) { 
                    console.log("error");
                    console.log(e);
                },           
            });
    });
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<kendo-grid id="#PoGrid" k-data-source="dataSource"
            k-columns="gridColumns"
            k-editable="'inline'"
            k-toolbar="['create']"
            k-sortable="true"
            k-pageable="true"
            k-resizeable="true"
            k-on-change="onChange(kendoEvent)"
            k-selectable="true">
</kendo-grid>
```

Could somebody help with this issue?

Today I notised that `/api/po/postpo` send same object at any time when I click create/destroy/update button. I checked that code not exucete this action at other places, also I cleaned browsed cashe and cookies. Can be it is Kendo UI bug?